# Can these wall braces be removed?

Tags: walls, framing, garage

My detached garage was rebuilt in 2015, and 2 of the walls have metal braces with kerfs cut into the studs. The walls are sheathed with tongue and groove. The wall in the picture is 2x4’s 24” on center, with one of the studs sistered. Are these braces structural or were they temporary during the rebuild? I’m in the process of insulating my garage and these braces are keep me from touching thoseb2 wallls. I don’t want to place insulation because the braces will compress it, reducing the r-value. Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking to a licensed contractor, we determined these were temporary during the remodel. These strips are only meant to be in place before siding is added to the exterior.

Comment: Hello, and welcome back to Home Improvement. Thanks for giving us the final answer; this will help future visitors.

Comment: What type of siding is on the outside? Many types of siding are not structural. I have never seen this type of diagonal used for temporary bracing, temporary bracing is typically a 1X4 or larger nailed over the face of the wall, not a "T: brace cut into the face of the wall with a saw kerf.. Unless perhaps it is just a "drive" from the HVAC guy nailed over the face.

Comment: Siding is T&G 1 x 6. I looked up the specific brace on the manufacturer's web site, which stated the brace is only equivalent to a 1 x 3. I'd have to check again to find the site, it was a few months ago.

Answer (score 5):

They must stay. They are structural and the small amount of compression in that small space will not affect the performance of the insulation as much as a receptacle or light switch.

Comment: Thank you. Would the braces cause issues with drywall with it not sitting flush against the studs?

Comment: It will put a mild bump over the area, the metal is not much more than a 1/16" thick. In some cases, the framing on any given wall varies along its faces that much if not more

Comment: Agree completely, but if you wanted your studs to be plumb to put drywall on, you can buy cardboard shims and staple them on the face of the stud. I wouldn't bother, though, as the end result would look the same both ways.

Comment: What type of siding is on the outside? Many types of siding are not structural. I have never seen this type of diagonal used for temporary bracing, temporary bracing is typically a 1X4 or larger nailed over the face of the wall, not a "T: brace cut into the face of the wall with a saw kerf.. Unless perhaps it is just a "drive" from the HVAC guy nailed over the face.